# Open a secured PDF version 1.7

Tags: windows, pdf, filesystems, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader

Since few days I am trying to open a secured PDF in version 1.7 (an example of a PDF : https://gd.lu/resa/4mgQHL ) to get the text inside.

When I am trying to open the PDF with Adobe Reader (XI), PDF Xchange or IE, it's working fine : I can read it.

But when I want to open it with Chrome, aspose.PDF, spire.PDF, Foxit or ImageMagick.Net I have this message :

> The document you are trying to load requires Adobe Reader 8 or higher.
>   You may not have the Adobe Reader installed or your viewing
>   environment may not be properly configured to use Adobe Reader. For
>   information on how to install Adobe Reader and configure your viewing
>   environment please see http://www.adobe.com/go/pdf_forms_configure.

Does anyone have an idea to solve my problem ?

Edit :
The problem seems to be the XFA and not the security. Adobe Acrobat/Reader and PDF-XChange, only them are able to open properly the PDF.

Comment: How to solve the problem: Use one of the PDF viewers which work… However, the security settings won't allow copying text from the document…

Comment: I want to use aspose, spire or others to extract the text of the PDF. This option is not available on adobe acrobat XI because the PDF is secured.

Comment: There is a reason why the creator of the document added the security. In order to do what you want, you would better contact the creator/issuer of the document and request an unprotected version.

Comment: The security is not the problem. Aspose, Spire and others are able to extract the text of a secured PDF. QPDF make a copy of the PDF without the security but the problem seems to be the XFA. Only Adobe Acrobat/Reader & PDF-XChange are able to open properly a PDF with XFA after few tests...